# Get system locale language code in bash for a dynamic path

Tags: bash

Here is my bash-file:

```
#!/bin/bash
PathToParentDir="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
sudo linguist-qt4 $PathToParentDir/translate_de.ts
```

What I need is that my bash script automatically detects the system language `de` and inserts that after `translate_`. All i know is that i can type `locale -a`but that return too much words. I am totally new to bash...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be what you need:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

lang=$(locale | grep LANGUAGE | cut -d= -f2 | cut -d_ -f1)

PathToParentDir="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
sudo linguist-qt4 $PathToParentDir/translate_$lang.ts
```

Comment: This returns `de_DE:en`, is there also a way that only shows the first two letters?

Comment: @user2366975 Yes, see my new edits.

Comment: perfect, thanks! After your initial post I understood the `cut`method, and I tried to split it up behind `_` in a second command which did not work for me^^ well seems like i did another mistake and did not understand it properly

Comment: @user2366975 By running the command `locale` you will get all the data inside, then simply grep for the line you want to keep. In my case i use `lang=$(locale | grep LANG | cut -d= -f2 | cut -d_ -f1)` to get lowercase locale indicator.

Comment: While `cut`ing on some `grep`ed output works one can slim process stack down a bit with `awk`, eg `locale | awk -F"[_.]" '/LANGUAGE/{print tolower($2)}'` which outputs the same results.

Comment: I needed to fetch the current locale string in the format `en_US.UTF-8` for a raspberry pi setup script and this did the trick. The LANGUAGE entry seems to be blank in my Ubuntu install.

`$(locale | grep LANG= | cut -d= -f2)`